# Copying a class that inherits from a class with pure virtual methods?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I've not used C++ in a while, and I've become far too comfortable with the ease-of-use of real languages.

At any rate, I'm attempting to implement the Command pattern, and I need to map a number of command object implementations to string keys. I have an STL map of string to Command, and I'd like to copy the Command.

Essentially,

```
Command * copiedCommand = new Command( commandImplementation );
```

And I'd like to retain the functionality of commandImplementation. Since Command has the pure virtual function `execute`, this doesn't work. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you show more code? I don't see how the tile of your question is related to the body. ;-)

Comment: An STL map of string to Command pointers, you mean?

Comment: For real... I mean come one! Even if you don't like C++, saying it's not a **real language**...

Comment: I didn't mean that in the sense that it can't be used to make real applications. It's ability to do such is vacuously proven. I meant it in the sense that it is not of the same caliber as any language I would ever choose to solve a problem. For real-time systems, C/C++ may always be faster, but technology has shown us that even games and video rendering apps will move to virtual machines shortly. Hell, remember when Quake 2 was the hit title? It now runs in my browser :P.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it would be to have add this to your Command class:

```
public:
   virtual Command * Clone() const = 0;
```

... and then in the various subclasses of Command, implement Clone() to return a copy of the object:

```
public:
   virtual Command * Clone() const {return new MyCommandSubclass(*this);}
```

Once that's done, you can then do what you want like this:

```
Command * copiedCommand = commandImplementation->Clone();
```

Comment: I bet Go makes this more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern

> A prototype pattern is a creational
> design pattern used in software
> development when the type of objects
> to create is determined by a
> prototypical instance, which is cloned
> to produce new objects. This pattern
> is used to:
>
> - avoid subclasses of an
>   object creator in the client
>   application, like the abstract factory
>   pattern does.
> - avoid the inherent cost
>   of creating a new object in the
>   standard way (e.g., using the 'new'
>   keyword) when it is prohibitively
>   expensive for a given application.
>
> To
> implement the pattern, declare an
> abstract base class that specifies a
> pure virtual clone() method. Any class
> that needs a "polymorphic constructor"
> capability derives itself from the
> abstract base class, and implements
> the clone() operation.
>
> The client,
> instead of writing code that invokes
> the "new" operator on a hard-coded
> class name, calls the clone() method
> on the prototype, calls a factory
> method with a parameter designating
> the particular concrete derived class
> desired, or invokes the clone() method
> through some mechanism provided by
> another design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If `Command` is an abstract class, you won't be able to call the copy constructor directly.  Instead, you might consider creating a `clone()` method that returns a deep copy of the object.  This could also be a pure-virtual method that returns your base class, such as:

```
class Command {
    public:
        virtual Command* clone(void) const = 0;
};
```